# Eomonth in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-udf, vba

How can I use this function in a user-defined function? I just cannot use a reference to a cell.

```
Function SONxMonth()
   SONxMonth = EOMONTH(A1, 0) + 1
End Func
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `WorksheetFunction` which are used as a container for Microsoft Excel worksheet functions that can be called from Visual Basic.

`Function SONxMonth()
       SONxMonth = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Range("A1"), 0)
End Func`

Comment: My A1 got value of date(2015,4,1), the function return a value of 32, when format changed to date, the value shown being 1/2/1900.

Comment: Seems it take A1 as zero value.

Comment: Also can I use relative notation in the function like RC[-1] ?

Comment: WorkSheetFunction.EOMONTH(Range("A1"), 0) + 1 do the trick, but if i want not to refer to A1 but a cell left to the active cell, what should be placed instead of Range("A1") ?

Answer (score 0):

If you always want the function to do the task on the cell to the left you can use a named formula and skip the VBA code. That is, you are assuming the argument is in the cell to the left - a common situation in excelcell.

Set the cursor in cell B1 and then define the name

```
SONxMonth as =EOMONTH(A1, 0) + 1
```

It will now always reference the argument from the left hand cell.

You have created in RC notation this:

```
=EOMONTH(RC[-1], 0) + 1
```

Comment: Is the first line containing code all literal code? Why `as =`? Is there an implied or default data type?

Comment: OK, the OP has left building: *"Last seen more than 4 years ago"*. Perhaps somebody else can chime in?